# Get data from 'FOREACH' generated table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, foreach

I am trying to make an Edit Form. I use re-insert method.
This is the `t_job_detail` table I'd like to edit (this is dummy):

```
ID    Job ID     Name     Score
A1        B1     Claire      75
A1        B2     Claire      80
A2        B4       Dart      60
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form id='f_edit' method='post' action='<?php echo site_url('con_atk/edit_data'); ?>'>
   <div>//header div </div>

   <?php foreach($test as $row){ ?> //$test = data from mysql query when I select ID = A1
   <div>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='arr[0]['job_id']' value='<?php echo $row['job_id']; ?>'</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='arr[1]['name']' value='<?php echo $row['name]; ?>'</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='arr[2]['score']' value='<?php echo $row['score']; ?>'</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
   </div>
   <?php }; ?>

   <div><input type='submit' value='update' /></div>
</form
```

When I select ID = A1, there are two table generated because I have two results returned from database. However, when I send this form to my controller (`site_url('con_atk/edit_data')`) only one table value is sent.

How can I make all the data from the generated table is recorded and  sent to my controller? Maybe in a form of array or json.

This is my controller:

```
//FORM EDIT
public function edit_data()
{
    $details = $this->input->post('arr');
    print_r($details); //only data from first table is printed

   die;

   //delete ID = A1  process
   //insert new data process
}
```

**Note**:

- I am using Code Igniter MVC
- I am open to any php compatible solution (Javascript,jQuery,AJAX)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your foreach loop to use a key as follows:

```
<?php foreach($test as $key => $value){ ?>
<div>
     <table>
     <tr>
         <td><input type='text' name='arr[$key]['job_id']' value='<?php echo $value['job_id']; ?>'</td>
         <td><input type='text' name='arr[$key]['name']' value='<?php echo $value['name]; ?>'</td>
         <td><input type='text' name='arr[$key]['score']' value='<?php echo $value['score']; ?>'</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
</div>
<?php }; ?>
```

Right now, the inputs in your rows are all posting with the exact same names as each other. They need to be unique in order to be able to access all of them once the form is posted.